# Justify text inside itemize environment with beamer class

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, lists, itemize

I would like to justify text inside an `itemize` environment with the `beamer` class. Text appears to be justified by default with the `article` class, but not with the `beamer` class.

The following code justifies text left and right:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[1-1]
    \end{itemize}
    \end{document}
```

The following code does not:

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[1-1]
    \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

I have tried this:

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \let\olditemize=\itemize 
    \renewenvironment{itemize}{\olditemize\justify}{\endlist} 
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[1-1]
    \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

but it won't justify text on the right. Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: Oh, yes, it's true. I hadn't realized. I'll delete my comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`beamer` has its own ways and, in particular, it redefines many standard LaTeX environments/commands; in particular, it redefines the basic list-like environments `itemize`, `enumerate` and `description`.

Here's, for example, the definition of `\itemize` as given in `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`:

```
\renewcommand{\itemize}[1][]{%
  \beamer@ifempty{#1}{}{\def\beamer@defaultospec{#1}}%
  \ifnum \@itemdepth >2\relax\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \beamer@computepref\@itemdepth% sets \beameritemnestingprefix
    \usebeamerfont{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body begin}%
    \list
      {\usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}}
      {\def\makelabel##1{%
          {%
            \hss\llap{{%
                \usebeamerfont*{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
                \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}##1}}%
          }%
        }%
      }
  \fi%
  \beamer@cramped%
  \raggedright% 
  \beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip%
}
```

as you can see, `\itemize` internally uses `\raggedright`. The best approach to keep things overlay specification-aware is to redefine `\itemize` to use `\justifying` (from the `ragged2e` package) instead; the following code shows this redefinition in an actual document:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\itemize}[1][]{%
  \beamer@ifempty{#1}{}{\def\beamer@defaultospec{#1}}%
  \ifnum \@itemdepth >2\relax\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \beamer@computepref\@itemdepth% sets \beameritemnestingprefix
    \usebeamerfont{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body begin}%
    \list
      {\usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}}
      {\def\makelabel##1{%
          {%
            \hss\llap{{%
                \usebeamerfont*{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
                \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}##1}}%
          }%
        }%
      }
  \fi%
  \beamer@cramped%
  \justifying% NEW
  %\raggedright% ORIGINAL
  \beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1->\lipsum[2]
\item<2>\lipsum[2]
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

As a final note, I would suggest you to consider if this redefinition is really needed at all; frames with too much text (like the one I just build for the example) are to be avoided in a presentation.

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo, Thanks Ian, that does it!
I just want to answer your question Gonzalo, the reason for wanting to have text justified within a beamer document is that I alternate frames designed for presentation and slides designed for the handout version (tagging with "beamer" or "handout"). I typeset some of the "handout" frames as plain text for reading, for instance writing out page-length proofs or long explanations. There may be a better way to do this, but I've found it to be easy to do this way.

Comment: @PatrickT: I've flagged your (now deleted) answer for Moderatos attention, asking them if there's something they can do to help you with your accounts. Anyway, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 9):

Try this.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\let\olditem\item
\renewcommand\item{\olditem\justifying}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[1-1]
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But now `\item` is no longer overlay specification-aware.

Answer (score 9):

use the package `ragged2e`

```
\begin{itemize}
        \justifying
    \item...
    \item...
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: This more like a comment than a qualified answer

Comment: @user31729 but it seems to do the job!

Answer (score 5):

> Please don't try this at home - I am sure this will break all kind of stuff I am currently not thinking about and if it does, don't complain to me.

A very very dirty hack: as all itemize/description/enumerate environments in beamer are set using `raggedright`, changing the meaning of `raggedright` might give the desired output:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\raggedright}{\justifying}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \lipsum[66]
        \end{itemize}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item \lipsum[75]
        \end{enumerate}
        \begin{description}
            \item[Item] \lipsum[66]
        \end{description}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: dangerous solution :) :) :). maybe someone should contact `beamer` maintainer(s) and suggest to redefine this part of `beamer` code with introduce new command, something like `\listalign` which default meaning is `\riggedright` but can be with `renewcommand` changed to what ever (from `\justifying` to \Raggedright`) if someone wish to do this.

Comment: @Zarko Indeed :) Please feel free to contact the beamer maintainer.

Comment: @samcarter  I like your radical thinking!

Answer (score 3):

I was using Gonzalo's solution for years, then noticed that it was not working for lists within lists (like enumerate within enumerate etc.). Redefining the list environments to include `\justify` works for me, though I am not sure whether this brings any drawbacks.

Paste this in the preample:

```
\let\tempItemizeBeg\itemize
\let\tempItemizeEnd\enditemize
\renewenvironment{itemize}{\tempItemizeBeg \justifying}{\tempItemizeEnd}
\let\tempEnumerateBeg\enumerate
\let\tempEnumerateEnd\endenumerate
\renewenvironment{enumerate}{\tempEnumerateBeg \justifying}{\tempEnumerateEnd}
```