# Beamer justified numbering

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, enumerate, itemize

I am trying to follow [the solution to give justified environments in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50019/106804) without needing to explicitly type `justifying` everywhere. However, I am not sure how to get the numbering correct, as the enumerate item should start at 1. (I have no idea how to do the `description` field as well, but that's an extra, as I rarely use it). I have tried naively adding a `+1` where item occurs, but without success.

[image]

**CODE / MWE**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\itemize}[1][]{%
    \beamer@ifempty{#1}{}{\def\beamer@defaultospec{#1}}%
    \ifnum \@itemdepth >2\relax\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \beamer@computepref\@itemdepth% sets \beameritemnestingprefix
    \usebeamerfont{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body begin}%
    \list
    {\usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}}
    {\def\makelabel##1{%
            {%
                \hss\llap{{%
                        \usebeamerfont*{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
                        \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}##1}}%
            }%
        }%
    }
    \fi%
    \beamer@cramped%
    \justifying% NEW
    %\raggedright% ORIGINAL
    \beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip%
}
\makeatother

% My attempt at getting enumerate working. 
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\enumerate}[1][]{%
    \beamer@ifempty{#1}{}{\def\beamer@defaultospec{#1}}%
    \ifnum \@itemdepth >2\relax\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \beamer@computepref\@itemdepth% sets \beameritemnestingprefix
    \usebeamerfont{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body begin}%
    \list
    {\usebeamertemplate{enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix item}}
    {\def\makelabel##1{%
            {%
                \hss\llap{{%
                        \usebeamerfont*{enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
                        \usebeamercolor[fg]{enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix item}##1}}%
            }%
        }%
    }
    \fi%
    \beamer@cramped%
    \justifying% NEW
    %\raggedright% ORIGINAL
    \beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \lipsum[66]
        \end{itemize}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item \lipsum[75]
        \end{enumerate}
        \begin{description}
            \item[Item] \lipsum[66]
        \end{description}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: for enumerate probably you need to redefine`enumerate` definition. i suspect that it has defined enumeration counter. similarly for `description`

Answer (score 4):

As the enumerate and description are different enough that "guessing" the code based on the itemize environment won't work - however you can find the all definitions in `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty` and modify them in the same way then itemize:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\itemize}[1][]{%
    \beamer@ifempty{#1}{}{\def\beamer@defaultospec{#1}}%
    \ifnum \@itemdepth >2\relax\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \beamer@computepref\@itemdepth% sets \beameritemnestingprefix
    \usebeamerfont{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body begin}%
    \list
    {\usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}}
    {\def\makelabel##1{%
            {%
                \hss\llap{{%
                        \usebeamerfont*{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
                        \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}##1}}%
            }%
        }%
    }
    \fi%
    \beamer@cramped%
    \justifying% NEW
    %\raggedright% ORIGINAL
    \beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip%
}

\def\beamer@enum@{%
  \beamer@computepref\@itemdepth% sets \beameritemnestingprefix
  \usebeamerfont{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
  \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body begin}%
  \expandafter
    \list
      {\usebeamertemplate{\beamer@enumtempl}}
      {\usecounter\@enumctr%
        \def\makelabel##1{{\hss\llap{{%
                \usebeamerfont*{enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
                \usebeamercolor[fg]{enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix item}##1}}}}}%
  \beamer@cramped%
  \justifying
%  \raggedright%
  \beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip%
}

\def\@@description{%
  \advance\beamer@descdefault by \labelsep%
  \usebeamerfont{description body}%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{description body}%
  \usebeamertemplate{description body begin}%
  \list
  {}
  {\labelwidth\beamer@descdefault\leftmargin\beamer@descdefault\let\makelabel\beamer@descriptionitem}%
  \beamer@cramped%
%  \raggedright
\justifying
  \beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip%
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \lipsum[66]
        \end{itemize}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item \lipsum[75]
        \end{enumerate}
        \begin{description}
            \item[Item] \lipsum[66]
        \end{description}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]