# prevent indentation before item text, and hide bullets in Beamer

Tags: beamer, itemize

Using the following code, to justify item text, how can I prevent the indentation before the item text, and hide the bullets.

I tried `\hspace {-.2cm}` and `\item[]` but both did not work.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\let\olditem\item
\renewcommand\item{\olditem\justifying}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[1-1]
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you almost never need `\justifying`  which is the default for tex anyway. If you don't want bullets or indent why use the itemize environment? why not just `\begin{frame}\ipsum[1]\end{frame}` ??

Comment: `\item[]` would not work as you have defined it to be `\olditem\justifying[]` so `\olditem` won't see the `[]`

Comment: This was just a MWE. there are several items included in the original document.

Comment: so your question is even less clear: do you want to remove the bullet from all the items or just one?

Comment: I want to remove the bullet from all or selected items, with no indentation.

Comment: I'd have thought you could just have used `\item[]` (without the `\justifying` redefinition that stops `[]` and beamers `<>` options.) but I can't really guess what layout you intend with an itemized list with only some items bulleted. Hopefully samcarter's answer covers it anyway:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand why you use an itemization and not just normal text, but you can remove the bullet with `\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{}` and the indentation with `\setlength{\leftmargini}{0cm}`.

Be warned that you'll use all the nice beamer features like the possibility to use overlays with your `\item` redefinition. I suggest to use this redefinition of `\itemize` instead: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387884/36296

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\let\olditem\item
\renewcommand\item{\olditem\justifying}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{0cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
text 
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This was just a MWE. there are several items included in the original document.